# Web Scraper on Rpi 0 only grabs new data every 3-4 minutes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, raspberry-pi-zero

I wrote a python web scraper using the Beautiful Soup 4 library and am running it on a raspberry pi 0. I am grabbing data from `mlb.com/<insert a team name>/scores` so, for example, `mlb.com/padres/scores` or `mlb.com/cubs/scores`. The sites look slightly different when games are scheduled, in progress, or have ended. My program is for when the game is in progress.

The issue I am facing is that when I try to run the program in a loop to continually grab information as the game progresses (ideally my program would catch every pitch update), my web scraper does not keep up. It seems that the web scraper grabs the HTML once every 3-4 minutes and then if I continue to run it, it gets the data from a cache somewhere. When I refresh the page on my desktop, I can see the page has updated. But when the program is running on my Raspberry pi 0, it does not see the updates to the page for roughly 3-4 minutes.

For example, when I run the script on my rpi, it will capture a moment in the game. 2 outs, 1 ball, 2 strikes, etc. When viewing on my desktop browser, the game will continue and the webpage will update. 2 outs, 2 balls, 2 strikes..... 2 outs, 3 balls, 2 strikes... etc. But if I continue running the script on my rpi it will still see/show 2 outs, 1 ball, 2 strikes which does not match what I see on my desktop. Then after roughly 3-4 minutes, my rpi will update and once again match what I see on my desktop.

I can post code if necessary, but I'm leaning towards this being a lack of understanding of how the BS4 library works. I'll be reading through the documentation in the meantime but hopefully someone knows my issue. Thanks!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://www.mlb.com/astros/scores'
while again:
        # Connect to the URL
        uClient = uReq(url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        
        #set html parsing
        page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
        data = page_soup.find('div',{'data-test-mlb':'singleGameContainer'})
```

https://github.com/MattNemeth/led-cle-indians

Comment: After running my program on different platforms the problem persists. The web scrapers see the same thing. They grab the same html. However, browsers with the web page open see different html. So my question now is what would cause the web scrapers to see different html than a browser?

Answer (score 1):

beautifulsoup extract information from HTML but it does not perform the request per se. If you have saved a web page in html on your drive and always parse it with beautifulsoup, it is never updated. You have to get your webpage again with `requests.get` or equivalent.

Example:

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from time import sleep, time 

prev = "" 
# Set the URL you want to webscrape from 
url = 'https://www.mlb.com/astros/scores' 
start = time() 
while True: 
    t0 = time() 
    # Connect to the URL 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    page_html = r.text 

    t1 = time() 
    print(f"{t1 - start:.2f}s {t1-t0:.2f}s", page_html == prev) 
    prev = page_html 
    sleep(10)
```

The code above gives me the following output:

```
0.15s 0.15s False
10.38s 0.22s True
20.56s 0.17s True
32.41s 1.83s True
42.57s 0.16s True
52.74s 0.16s True
62.90s 0.15s True
73.08s 0.17s True
83.25s 0.16s True
93.41s 0.15s True
103.57s 0.15s True
115.13s 1.55s False
125.29s 0.16s True
135.46s 0.16s True
145.63s 0.16s True
155.81s 0.17s True
166.07s 0.26s True
```

So the webpage is updating correctly

One thing that might be source of error though is your use of `BeautifulSoup.find` [here](https://github.com/MattNemeth/led-cle-indians/blob/master/scraper.py#L26) which will limit the output to only one result. I guess that it is intentional but if not, you might have your problem right there...

Comment: From what I understand, I am doing what you say I need to do which is why I'm confused it is not working. I tried to paste code with this comment but did not format properly. I'll try and edit my original post

Comment: Can you show some code? (in your original post, not in the comments) Not the whole thing but how you get the data and pass it to BS4. Also, it would be helpful if you time one iteration, just so that we can rule out that it is the program that is just slow

Comment: Apologies, I've never posted here before. I edited the original post. The only way I can see the timing being an issue is if the web request is not sequential meaning once I make that call, the program would continue and print the data it collected. When looping the program, it will print and take about 10 seconds to print again and usually it is the same data. I have the program on github if that is easier for you than me trying to explain lol

Comment: I'm going to try running it on a few different machines tonight and see if the issue persists across different platforms. I should have tried this sooner. I'm going to add more to my post to hopefully make my issue more clear. I think the raspberry pi could be the culprit after seeing your example. The use of find there is intentional. If you go to mlb.com/team name/scores then the team you have in the url will always be the first game container. I just want the info about a specific teams game as of now. Might gather info of all games later once I get it working for one team.

Thank youbtw!

Comment: I ran my program on my desktop. The scraper on my rpi and the scraper on my desktop see the same thing. The html that they pull is the same. However, when I open the web page in a browser, the html is not the same. I have no idea what would cause this. Any ideas? Edit: I think Javascript is what is causing my headaches. Sounds like it's updating the web page but not the source?

Comment: Javascript is not causing anything: BS4 is not a browser, it cannot run JS... Did you run the piece of code that I provided to verify that the error does not come from your program? If not, please do so. If the page ends up updating at some point, then the problem comes from your code, not the webpage